# How to safely alloy magnesium castings into aluminum?

Tags: transition-metals, alloy

I want to dissolve previously sand cast magnesium to molten aluminum to create an aluminum magnesium alloy. Of course I want to do this as safely, and inexpensively, as possible. I have an electric (resistive) furnace, so no flames.

Of course the normal response is to use an inert atmosphere but this will likely make the process uneconomical. I have 2kg of chunky magnesium casting. (old 70s VW beetle transmission housing) In the end I would like to have an Al-Mg alloy with about 7% being magnesium.

My initial thought was to get the aluminum up to temperature, preheat the magnesium chunk to about 500°C then submerge the magnesium into the aluminum and have it dissolve.

If the magnesium were hot enough to ignite under normal conditions, I wondered if the aluminum would prevent runaway ignition because it would be absorbing the heat from the reaction. Remember there will be 14x as much aluminum (by weight) compared to the magnesium being alloyed.

Of course I would do a limited volume test in order to try out the process. Maybe 300ml total volume. And the reaction would take place in an open top insulated furnace.

Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Heating magnesium in air seems not a good idea, and aluminum which also reacts very exothermically with oxygen is not going to be a good heat sink. Can you use a nitrogen atmosphere? It may still react but won't initiate combustion.

Comment: Magnesium burns in nitrogen too.

Comment: But can the nitrogen initiate combustion?

Comment: Temperature initiates combustion.

Comment: Bulk magnesium does not ignite easily. Molten magnesium in a crucible covered with a flux is not much worse than molten aluminium. Manipulations of the surface might cause local burning, but this can be minimised by blowing argon over the surface. This is way less worrying than you might expect.

Comment: If the magnesium is held below the surface of the molten aluminum, would there still be a significant reaction? As far as a covering flux, that is doable, but if it came to also using argon, that would be cost prohibited. Just not worth all the effort. Might as well just buy new alloy material.

Comment: I found a paper that might be informative to me question.  ---   A review on ignition mechanisms and characteristics of magnesium alloys --- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213956720300335

Comment: Magnesium melts at a lower temperature than Al, so just drop the Mg alloy into the molten aluminum and keep it covered with the aluminum. Note that as you solidify you will not end up with a consistent alloy composition.

Comment: My thought was that if it were submerged that it would not have oxygen to react with. I did find an example of this on http://forums.thehomefoundry.org/index.php?threads/alloying-aluminum-for-casting-and-machinability.164/.  =>[My last mag fire was an Audi valve cover.
About the same time I threw it in my big furnace it registered that it was lite, it ignited before i could get it back out, The furnace had a pool of about 50 lbs of aluminum so I submerged it in the pool, by keeping it submerged it contained most of the fire but that batch of aluminum was about 4% mag when i had it scanned.]

Comment: "Note that as you solidify you will not end up with a consistent alloy composition." If the solution was mixed well (stirred gently below the surface oxide layer" why could it not be consistent through the mix? That seems to be a normal procedure for alloying copper into aluminum. Is there some reason it will not work with magnesium?